# Trying to arrange list within list but can't arrange numbers properly

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

So right I'm working with a file with a bunch of lists within a list. I'm trying to arrange them by top 5 states and bottom 5 states for total number of participants.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter #not really using this right now
crimefile = open('APExam.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefile)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
L = sorted(allRows,key=lambda x: x[1])
for item in L:
print item[0],','.join(map(str,item[1:]))
```

Which prints something like this:

```
State  Total #,% passed,%female
Wyoming 0,0,0
New Hampshire 101,76,12
Utah 103,54,4
Mass 1067,67,18
Montana 11,55,0
Iowa 118,80,9
Alabama 126,79,17
Georgia 1261,51,18
Florida 1521,44,20
Illinois 1559,69,13
New Jersey 1582,74,15
Maine 161,67,16
```

This prints the file in a way that is nearly what I'm looking for but the total number of participants isn't sorted by the largest to lowest; it is sorted by looking at the first element. How do I change it to look more like:

```
New Jersey 1582,74,15
Illinois 1559,69,13
Florida 1521,44,20
Georgia 1261,51,18
Etc...
```

First time asking a question here, any help is appreciated! :)
Also, I trying not to use the .sort() or find() function or the "in" operator-- such as "if 6 in [5, 4, 7 6] ..."

Edit*: By changing L

```
L = sorted(allRows,key=lambda x: int(x[1]),reverse=True)
```

I've gotten to the point where I have the list going in descending order:

```
State  Total #,% passed,%female
California 4964,76,22
Texas 3979,62,23
New York 1858,69,20
Virginia 1655,60,19
Maryland 1629,66,20
New Jersey 1582,74,15
Illinois 1559,69,13
Florida 1521,44,20
```

Now I can't quite seem to figure out how to only take the top 5 and bottom 5 based on these totals...

Answer (score 1):

You goofed up the sorting. CSV files contain text, regardless of what that text may happen to be.

```
L = sorted(allRows,key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Comment: When I change up the code to this it yields the following error "L = sorted(allRows,key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Total #'"

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! Think I'll try to figure the rest out myself for a little while, but that helps a lot :)

Comment: Alright, so I tried for a couple hours to get it to give me only the top 5 and bottom 5 but basically everything I tried yielded either an error or just scrambled the list... Any suggestions?

Comment: Slice it. `L[:5]`, `L[-5:]`